# If $\sqrt {x+iy}=a+bi$ then prove that

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

If $\sqrt {x+iy}=a+bi$ then prove that $\sqrt {x-iy}=a-ib$

My Attempt 
$$\sqrt {x+iy}=a+bi$$
Squaring both sides 
$$x+iy=a^2+2iab+i^2.b^2$$
$$x+iy=a^2-b^2+2iab$$

How do I proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your question is:

> If $x,y,a,b\in\mathbb R$ and if $a+bi$ is a square root of $x+yi$, then prove that $a-bi$ is a square root of $x-yi$.

If so, note that\begin{align}a+bi\text{ is a square root of }x+yi&\iff(a+bi)^2=x+yi\\&\iff a^2-b^2+2abi=x+yi\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}a^2-b^2=x\\2ab=y\end{array}\right.\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}a^2-b^2=x\\-2ab=-y\end{array}\right.\\&\iff a^2-b^2-2abi=x-yi\\&\iff(a-bi)^2=x-yi.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The two square roots of $\,−1\,$ are indistinguishable, so any result that uses $\,i\,$ will also be true with $\,−i\,$ substituted for $\,i\,$ throughout. Technically, conjugation is an automorphism. You may think that this holds for square root of $\,2\,$, for example, but one root is positive and the other negative, although algebraically they are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Compare the real and imaginary parts to get $$x=a^2-b^2$$ and $$y=2ab$$ and use it for next question

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& x+iy=a^2-b^2+2iab \\
& x-iy=a^2-b^2-2iab = (a-ib)^2
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\overline{\sqrt{x+yi}}=\overline{a+bi}$

$\sqrt{x-yi}={a-bi}$